# Generators in Javascript; Project Euler #2

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, generator

I'm trying to learn javascript using project euler and I decided to try to force myself to learn about generators in javascript using [problem number 2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2) which asks us to:  `Find the sum of the even-valued terms in the fibonacci (f(n)) sequence such that f(n) < 4M , beginning with n=1 is 1, n=2 is 2, n=3 is 3 and so on`

My code below presently works but I'm hoping to get some input as I began learning javascript this week. I'm coming from a python background and any input that keeps that in mind would be heavily appreciated!

```
function* fib_gen() {
    var current = a = b = 1;

    while (true) {
        current = b;

        yield current;

        b = a + b;
        a = current;
    }
}

function solution() {
    sequence = fib_gen();
    even_fibs_total = 0;
    cur = sequence.next().value;

    while (cur < 4000000) {
        if (cur % 2 == 0) even_fibs_total += cur;
        cur = sequence.next().value;
    }

    return even_fibs_total
}

var time_pre = performance.now()
document.write(solution())
document.write('<br>')
var time_post = performance.now()
document.write('completed in ' + Math.round((time_post - time_pre)*100)/100 + ' seconds')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You have a few undeclared variables which means they become global. You want to use `var` (or `let` or `const`) always. Compare this:

```
var current = a = b = 1; // a and b are globals
```

To:

```
var current, a, b; // all variables are local
current = a = b = 1;
```

Same here:

```
sequence = fib_gen(); // not declared
even_fibs_total = 0; // not declared
cur = sequence.next().value; // not declared
```

Compare to:

```
var sequence = fib_gen();
var even_fibs_total = 0;
var cur = sequence.next().value;
```

2) Conventions:

- Name your variables with camelCase instead snake_case.
- Use `===` instead of `==` unless you know you really really need `==` (tip: you probably don't).
- Always write `if` statements with braces, even if one line, for better readability and refactoring.

3) Generators are iterators, and iterators can be iterated with the `for..of` loop. If your environment supports generators it probably supports `for..of`:

```
function solution() {
  var evenFibsTotal = 0;

  for (var cur of fibGen()) {
    if (cur >= 4000000) {
      break;
    }
    if (cur % 2 === 0) {
      evenFibsTotal += cur;
    }
  }

  return evenFibsTotal;
}
```

4) If you have ES6 support (or compilation via Babel) you can use destructuring assignment to simplify the fibonnaci function:

```
function* fibGen() {
  var a = 1;
  var b = 1;
  while (true) {
    yield b;
    [a, b] = [b, a + b];
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the helpful advice! can you go a little more into the global vs. local scoping when using the `var` keyword? in addition, when would the `for... of` vs. `for... in` iteratator syntax be used? in python it's all the same so i'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `var` instead of `let`?